# Help solving variable separable ODE: $y' = \frac{1}{2} a y^2 + b y - 1$ with $y(0)=0$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am studying for an exam about ODEs and I am struggling with one of the past exam questions. The past exam shows one exercise which asks us to solve:
$$y' = \frac{1}{2} a y^2 + b y - 1$$with $y(0)=0$

The solution is given as
$$y(x) = \frac{2 \left( e^{\Gamma x} - 1 \right)}{(b + \Gamma)(e^{\Gamma x} - 1) + 2\Gamma},$$ with $\Gamma = \sqrt{b^2 + 2a}$

---

I am really getting stuck at this exercise and would love to have someone show me how this solution is derived.

One thing I did find out is that this ODE is variable separable. That is,
$$y' = g(x)h(y) = (1) \cdot (\frac{1}{2} ay^2 + by - 1),$$ and therefore the solution would result from solving
$$\int \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2} ay^2 + by - 1} dy = \int dx + C,$$
where C is clearly zero because $y(0) = 0$.

I am now getting stuck at solving the left integral. Could anyone please show me the steps?

---

**UPDATE**

So I came quite far with @LutzL solution, however my answers seems to slightly deviate from the solution given above. These are the steps I performed (continuing from @LutzL's answer):

You complete the square $\frac12ay^2+by-1=\frac12a(y+\frac ba)^2-1-\frac{b^2}{2a}$ and use this to inspire the change of coordinates $u=ay+b$ leading to
$$
\int \frac{dy}{\frac12ay^2+by-1}=\int\frac{2\,du}{u^2-2a-b^2}
$$
and for that your integral tables should give a form using the inverse hyperbolic tangent. Or you perform a partial fraction decomposition for
$$
\frac{2Γ}{u^2-Γ^2}=-\frac{1}{u+Γ}+\frac{1}{u-Γ}
$$
and find the corresponding logarithmic anti-derivatives,
$$
\ln|u-Γ|-\ln|u+Γ|=Γx+c,\\ \frac{u-Γ}{u+Γ}=Ce^{Γx},\ C=\pm e^c
$$
which you now can easily solve for $u$ and then $y$.

Given that $y(0) = 0$ we have $u(y(0)) = u(0) = b$ and therefore the final equation becomes
$$\frac{u(0)-Γ}{u(0)+Γ}= \frac{b-Γ}{b+Γ}=Ce^{Γ\cdot0} = Ce^{Γ \cdot 0} = C$$
Now by first isolating $u$ I get
$$u - \Gamma = u C e^{\Gamma x} + \Gamma C e^{\Gamma x} \Rightarrow \\
u \left( 1 - C e^{ \Gamma x} \right) = \Gamma \left( 1 + C e^{\Gamma x} \right) \Rightarrow \\
u = \frac{\Gamma \left( 1 + C e^{\Gamma x} \right)}{\left( 1 - C e^{ \Gamma x} \right)}$$
Now substituting u and C gives
$$ay + b= \frac{\Gamma \left( 1 + \frac{b-Γ}{b+Γ} e^{\Gamma x} \right)}{\left( 1 - \frac{b-Γ}{b+Γ} e^{ \Gamma x} \right)} \Rightarrow \\
y = \frac{\Gamma \left( 1 + \frac{b-Γ}{b+Γ} e^{\Gamma x} \right) - b \left( 1 - \frac{b-Γ}{b+Γ} e^{ \Gamma x} \right)}{a \left( 1 - \frac{b-Γ}{b+Γ} e^{ \Gamma x} \right)}$$

Now using the fact that $\Gamma = \sqrt{b^2 + 2a} \Rightarrow a = \frac{(\Gamma + b)(\Gamma - b)}{2}$ we get that
$$y = \frac{2 \left( \Gamma \left( 1 + \frac{b-\Gamma }{b+\Gamma } e^{\Gamma x} \right) - b \left( 1 - \frac{b-\Gamma }{b+\Gamma } e^{ \Gamma x} \right) \right)}{(\Gamma + b)(\Gamma - b) \left( 1 - \frac{b-\Gamma }{b+\Gamma } e^{ \Gamma x} \right)}  \\
= \frac{2 \left( (\Gamma - b) + (\Gamma + b) \frac{b-\Gamma }{b+ \Gamma } e^{\Gamma x} \right)}{(\Gamma + b)(\Gamma - b) \left( 1 - \frac{b-\Gamma }{b+\Gamma } e^{ \Gamma x} \right)} \\
= \frac{2 \left( (\Gamma - b) - (\Gamma + b) \frac{\Gamma - b }{b+ \Gamma } e^{\Gamma x} \right)}{(\Gamma + b)(\Gamma - b) \left( 1 - \frac{b-\Gamma }{b+\Gamma } e^{ \Gamma x} \right)}$$
Now cancelling the terms $(b + \Gamma)$ and $(b - \Gamma)$ wherever possible and multiplying denominator and nominator by -1 gives
$$y = \frac{2 \left(  e^{\Gamma x} - 1 \right)}{(\Gamma + b) \left( \frac{b-\Gamma }{b+\Gamma } e^{ \Gamma x} - 1 \right)} $$

So clearly, I got the nominator right, but I can not seem to get the denominator to equal $(b + \Gamma)(e^{\Gamma x} - 1) + 2\Gamma$. Can someone rescue me and show me what I did wrong?

Maybe it helps if I say that x is always positive?

Comment: Hint: complete the square, so that you get the integral into a form that (after a linear substitution) looks like it should be an arctan.

Comment: @PatrickStevens I am not very familiar with integrals involving arctan. Especially how would I get rid of an arctan as it does not seem to appear in the final solution?

Comment: @Harry49 are you sure about this, as it seems that I have a constant in my ODE which does not seem to be present in a Bernoulli differential equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You complete the square $\frac12ay^2+by-1=\frac12a(y+\frac ba)^2-1-\frac{b^2}{2a}$ and use this to inspire the change of coordinates $u=ay+b$ leading to
$$
\int \frac{dy}{\frac12ay^2+by-1}=\int\frac{2\,du}{u^2-2a-b^2}
$$
and for that your integral tables should give a form using the inverse hyperbolic tangent. Or you perform a partial fraction decomposition for
$$
\frac{2Γ}{u^2-Γ^2}=-\frac{1}{u+Γ}+\frac{1}{u-Γ}
$$
and find the corresponding logarithmic anti-derivatives,
$$
\ln|u-Γ|-\ln|u+Γ|=Γx+c,\\ \frac{u-Γ}{u+Γ}=Ce^{Γx},\ C=\pm e^c
$$
which you now can easily solve for $u$ and then $y$.

Comment: +1 The only answer that's able to follow what the solution was hinting at. Great job

Comment: @LutzL your answer really helped and I almost finished the question! However I am stuck at a little part where I cannot get the denominator right... See the original answer. If you could help me about with this very last bit then I gladly offer you a beer!

Comment: Your given solution is wrong. In the segment between stationary solutions containing $0$, $(-\frac2{Γ-b},\frac2{Γ+b})$, the right side is negative, so the solution should fall from $\frac2{Γ+b}$ for $x=-\infty$ to $-\frac2{Γ-b}$ for $x=\infty$. In the given solution, it is the other way around. In our denominator you just have to collect $(Γ+b)+(Γ-b)e^{Γx}=(Γ-b)(e^{Γx}-1)+2Γ$.

Comment: I guess making mistakes is what allows one to learn! Unfortunately I can not really detect where in my derivation I exactly started making an error. Could you show me where I missed a step?

Comment: You did not make an error, the solution that was given to you is wrong. It should have $e^{-Γx}$ instead of $e^{Γx}$ to get it right using minimal changes.

Comment: Then I think what might be wrong here... In an attempt of me to simplify the equation to post it online for easier understanding, I have made a slight substitution of which I thought would be harmless. In short, the question posted above actually solves $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{2} ay(x)^2+by(x)−1$. But what I was truly looking for was the solution for $\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}ay(T-t)^2+by(T-t)−1$ where I have substituted $T-t$ for $x$, not knowing that this would change the solution. Do you think I can rescue the calculations elegantly or I have to start from scratch again?

Comment: Is the derivative on the left also at $(T-t)$? If not that changes radically the problem class, if yes, then yes, $\frac{d}{dt}(y(T-t))=-y'(T-t)$ so that a critical minus sign is missing.

Comment: It was the latter with the critical minus sign missing. I was able to obtain the exact solution of the professor using your method and hints! Thanks a lot! If you PM me I gladly offer you a beer for your help :)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't drink beer and rarely drink wine.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [Riccati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation) equation. Let us introduce the change of variable $z = y+\alpha$. The differential equation $y' = \frac{1}{2}ay^2 + by - 1$ rewrites as
\begin{aligned}
z' &= \frac{a}{2}(z^2-2\alpha z + \alpha^2) + b(z-\alpha) - 1\\
&= \frac{a}{2}z^2 + (b-a\alpha)z + \frac{a}{2}\alpha^2 - b\alpha - 1 \, .
\end{aligned}
If $\alpha$ is chosen so that the constant term $\frac{1}{2}a\alpha^2 - b\alpha - 1$ vanishes, e.g. $\alpha=\frac{b + \Gamma}{a}$ with $\Gamma = \sqrt{b^2+2a}$, then this differential equation may be viewed as a [Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation) differential equation. The latter can be solved by setting $u=z^{-1}$, which satisfies the linear ODE
$$
u' -\Gamma u = -\frac{a}{2}  \, .
$$
The solution with initial condition $u(0)=\alpha^{-1}$ is
$$
u (x) = \left(\alpha^{-1}-\frac{a}{2\Gamma}\right) e^{\Gamma x} +\frac{a}{2\Gamma} \, ,
$$
from which we deduce the [expression](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%27(x)+%3D+1%2F4*(gamma%5E2+-+b%5E2)*y(x)%5E2+%2B+b*y(x)+-+1+and+y(0)%3D0) of $y = u^{-1}-\alpha$ using the identity $a = \frac{\Gamma^2 - b^2}{2}$:
$$
y(x) = \frac{2 \left(1 - e^{\Gamma x}\right)}{(\Gamma - b)\, e^{\Gamma x} + \Gamma + b} \, .
$$

Comment: This is also the solution method for a Ricatti equation if one solution $y_0$ is known: to rewrite everything in terms of $y_0+z$. Here we have the obvious constant solutions at stationary points.

Answer (score 0):

write $$\int \frac{\frac{dy}{dx}}{\frac{1}{2}ay(x)^2+by(x)-1}dx=\int1dx$$
$$\frac{2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b+ay(x)}{\sqrt{-2a-b^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{-2a-b^2}}=x+C$$
$$y(x)=\frac{-b+\sqrt{-2a-b^2}\tan\left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-2a-b^2}(x+C)\right)}{a}$$

Comment: Unfortunately I am not very experienced in the form of trigonometric functions. How would one go from this solution with arctan to the solution as posted by the professor?